# Weird issues with Syslog-ng and apt-get

Tags: apt, syslog

So, I had a weird scenario just happen and I was just hoping someone might know what happened for my own edification. Basically, a while back I installed syslog-ng v 3.3.6 using

```
sudo apt-get install syslog-ng
```

I wanted to update my version of syslog-ng that I was running but after running install and checking:

```
sudo syslog-ng -V
```

it said it was still running 3.3.6.  Even when I ran an

```
sudo apt-get remove syslog-ng
```

the output would say it was removing but syslog was still running on the machine and still said it was running 3.3.6.

I updated my sources.list to point to the unofficial repos as per this [link](http://asylum.madhouse-project.org/projects/debian/).
 updated my apt-get 
and then ran

```
sudo apt-get remove libsyslog-ng-3.3.6
```

It removed 3.3.6 and installed 3.4.7, which is what I wanted to happen but I'm just really not sure *why* all of the above happened. Specifically, Why didn't it actually remove syslog-ng? and why did it remove 3.3.6 and auto-install 3.4.7?

Answer (score 0):

Just reboot: If syslog-ng is already running as a service than it is stored in RAM until it's terminated, thus updates and uninstall will have not effect.

Comment: Hm. I tried rebooting after the update and nothing happened. Never tried after the remove, though.

Comment: Strange that it didn't work after the update.  Perhaps it wasn't really updated, but just installed along side the old verstion.   `pkill syslog-ng` should work in place of a reboot